# ArrayList becomes null while writing to file

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, writer

My arraylist<"obj"> becomes null after trying to write to a file.

In WriteToFile class arraylist info becomes null after executing the last line

```
    writer.write(info.get(i).getIpadd().toString()+"\n");
```

It works on the first instance when i am writing another list to file but does not when i run it the 2nd instance. I dun understand why its happening. Below is the whole code and the stack trace.

WriteToFile Class:

```
public class WriteToFile {

public WriteToFile(ArrayList<Information> info,String location) 
{
    FileWriter writer=null;
    try
    {
        writer = new FileWriter(location); 
        System.out.println(info.size());
        for(int i=0;i<info.size()-1;i++) 
        {
          writer.write(info.get(i).getDate().toString()+",");
          writer.write(info.get(i).getAccount().toString()+",");
          writer.write(info.get(i).getStatus().toString()+",");
          writer.write(info.get(i).getIpadd().toString()+"\n");
          System.out.println(info.get(i).getAccount());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

}
```

StackTrace:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at WriteToFile.<init>(WriteToFile.java:17)
at Gen_Report.<init>(Gen_Report.java:45)
at Gen_Report.main(Gen_Report.java:57)
```

main:

```
public class Gen_Report {

public Gen_Report() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    //locate file and read all text from .log file to .csv
        //file is found.so read text from it and extract all date/time, email add ,accepts and rejects,ip add, delete
    Date date=new Date();
    String[] dateTokens=date.toString().split(" ");
    String dateString=dateTokens[2]+dateTokens[1]+dateTokens[5]+"_"+dateTokens[3].substring(0, 2)+dateTokens[3].substring(3,5)+dateTokens[3].substring(6, 8);

    String logFileLocation = "/Users/gundu_87/Documents/workspace/GenFLRReport/";

    ReaderFromLog rfl = new ReaderFromLog(logFileLocation+"radsecproxy.log");

    //include duplicates
    WriteToFile wtf = new WriteToFile(rfl.log,logFileLocation+dateString+"_FLRlogduplicates.txt");

    //exclude duplicates
    RemoveDuplicatesInList rdil = new RemoveDuplicatesInList(logFileLocation+dateString+"_FLRlogduplicates.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<rdil.log.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(rdil.log.get(i).getAccount());
    }
    wtf = new WriteToFile(rdil.log,logFileLocation+dateString+"_FLRlog.txt");

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Gen_Report gr= new Gen_Report();
}

}
```

Information class:

```
public class Information {

private String ipadd;
private String status;
private String account;
private String date;


public String getIpadd() {
    return ipadd;
}

public void setIpadd(String ipadd) {
    this.ipadd = ipadd;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(String account) {
    this.account = account;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
}
```

ReaderFromLog class

```
public class ReaderFromLog {


Scanner s1 = null;
String line=null;
ArrayList<Information> log;

public ReaderFromLog(String logFileLocation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    File logFile = new File(logFileLocation);

    if(!logFile.exists())
    {
        System.err.println("File not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            s1 = new Scanner(new FileReader(logFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.err.print("File not found");
        }
    }

    log=new ArrayList<Information>();
    //store into a array
    //exclude any repeats


    do{
        line=s1.nextLine();
        Information newUser = new Information();
        if(line.contains("Access-Accept for user"))
        {
            newUser.setStatus("Accept");
            String[] sb=line.split(" ");
            newUser.setAccount(sb[7]);
            int idx_Ipadd = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<sb.length;i++)
                if (sb[i].contentEquals("to"))
                    idx_Ipadd=i;
            newUser.setIpadd(sb[idx_Ipadd+1]+ " " + sb[idx_Ipadd+2]);
            newUser.setDate(sb[0]+ " "+sb[1] + " " +sb[2]+" " + sb[3].substring(0, 4));
            log.add(newUser);
        }
        else if(line.contains("Access-Reject for user"))
        {
            newUser.setStatus("Reject");
            String[] sb=line.split(" ");
            newUser.setAccount(sb[7]);
            int idx_Ipadd = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<sb.length;i++)
                if (sb[i].contentEquals("to"))
                    idx_Ipadd=i;
            newUser.setIpadd(sb[idx_Ipadd+1]+ " " + sb[idx_Ipadd+2]);
            newUser.setDate(sb[0]+ " "+sb[1] + " " +sb[2]+" " + sb[3].substring(0, 4));
            log.add(newUser);
        }
    }while(s1.hasNextLine());
}

}
```

RemoveDuplicate class:

```
public class RemoveDuplicatesInList {

Scanner s1 = null;
String line=null;
ArrayList<Information> log;

public RemoveDuplicatesInList(String duplicateFileLocation) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    File logFile = new File(duplicateFileLocation);

    if(!logFile.exists())
    {
        System.err.println("File not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        try 
        {
            s1 = new Scanner(new FileReader(logFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.err.print("File not found");
        }
    }

    log=new ArrayList<Information>();
    //store into a array
    //exclude any repeats
    do{
        boolean sameAccount=false;
        line=s1.nextLine();
        Information newUser = new Information();
        if(line.contains("Accept"))
        {
            newUser.setStatus("Accept");
            String[] sb=line.split(",");
            sameAccount=false;
            for(int i=0;i<log.size();i++)
                if(log.get(i).getAccount().contentEquals(sb[1]))
                {
                    sameAccount=true;
                    break;
                }
            if(!sameAccount)
            {
                newUser.setAccount(sb[1]);
                newUser.setIpadd(sb[3]);
                newUser.setDate(sb[0]);
                log.add(newUser);
            }

        }
        else if(line.contains("Reject"))
        {
            newUser.setStatus("Reject");
            String[] sb=line.split(",");
            for(int i=0;i<log.size();i++)
                if(log.get(i).getAccount().contentEquals(sb[1]))
                {
                    sameAccount=true;
                    break;
                }
            if(!sameAccount)
            {
                newUser.setAccount(sb[1]);
                newUser.setIpadd(sb[3]);
                newUser.setDate(sb[0]);
                log.add(newUser);
            }
        }
    }while(s1.hasNextLine());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check value of

```
info.get(i).getIpadd()
```

if value of this is null then .toString(0 will give you NullPointerException

Comment: it has a value.thanks man. i jus redit my code. merged the printing to file class wit the other classes. and it worked. i am bemused